# sort on multiple parameters in list of dictionaries/lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort on multiple parameters of list of dictionaries and lists. I checked [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72899/5582349]) .

I have a complex dictionary:

```
dict1 = 
{"outer_list" : [ 
#1st dict
{ "id" : 1,
"name" : "xyz",
"nested_list" : [{"id" : "5","key":"val"},{"id" : "4","key":"val"}]
},  

#2nd dict
{ 
"outer_id" : 11,
"name" : "abc",
"nested_list" : [{"id" : "12","key":"val"},{"id" : "8","key" : "val"}]
}
]  # outer_list ends
}  #dict1 ends
```

I want to sort on the key `name` and `nested_list[id]` and expected output :

```
 [{'outer_id': 11, 'name': 'abc', 'nested_list': [{'id': '8', 'key': 'val'}, {'id': '12', 'key': 'val'}]}, {'nested_list': [{'id': 4, 'key': 'val'}, {'id': 5, 'key': 'val'}], 'id': 1, 'name': 'xyz'}]
```

My attempt :

```
def sort_cluster(data):
    for items in data:
        item=items['outer_list']
        newlist = sorted(item, key=itemgetter('name'))
    print newlist


if __name__ == "__main__":
    list1=[]
    list1.append(dict1)
    sort_cluster(list1)
```

It sorts on name properly, next if i follow the same procedure for sorting on "newlist" for `nested_list[id]` , it's not working.

Comment: Can you show what the "same procedure" is that's not working? You must apply it to each `nested_list` separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort all the nested_lists, then sort the top-level list. You can do these in either order. For the keys, I prefer to use lambdas rather than `operator.itemgetter` here since we need to convert the result of one of the things to an int (I assume, based on your expected output), and you'd have to wrap the `operator.itemgetter` in a lambda anyway to do that.

```
def do_thing(dct):
    lst = dct["outer_list"]

    # Sort the nested_lists, assuming you want to sort by the numeric value of the "id" value
    for obj in lst:
        obj["nested_list"].sort(key=lambda d: int(d["id"]))

    # Sort the outer_list
    lst.sort(key=lambda d: d["name"])

    return lst
```

Then:

```
>>> do_thing(dict1)
[{'name': 'abc', 'outer_id': 11, 'nested_list': [{'key': 'val', 'id': '8'}, {'key': 'val', 'id': '12'}]}, 
 {'name': 'xyz', 'nested_list': [{'key': 'val', 'id': '4'}, {'key': 'val', 'id': '5'}], 'id': 1}]
```

Comment: It's working if i pass dictionary in a function. But i need to append dict in the list and then pass list in function. Any idea how can i do that ?

Comment: @Dave I don't understand your question.

Comment: -np, i figured it out.